# is there any way to inline just some selective calls to a function not all of them?

Tags: c++, function, inline, declaration

Is there any way to inline just some selective calls to a particular function not all of them? cause only form I know is declaring function as such at beginning and that's supposed to effect all calls to that function.

Comment: Or not - `inline` is just a hint, which the compiler is free to ignore. I believe that either it is ignored always, or never - it will be interesting to hear though what the experts say...

Comment: What's your *goal*? Don't ask the step. Why are you trying to mess with inlining?

Comment: @Gman_most of all curiosity, you got any problems with that by the way ???!!! ;)

Comment: @Péter Török: This has to be one of my biggest bugbears. `inline` is not _just_ a hint to the compiler. It changes the _one definition rule_ in ways that allow you to place function definitions in locations where you might expect the compiler to more easily be able to perform inline substitution of the function body. The rule changes still apply whether or not inline expansion is actually performed.

Comment: @Charles, thanks for the teaching - this is why it's worth being an SO member :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some background on inlining.

There are multiple phases where inlining might occur (for example):

- at compile time, the compiler may decide (or not) to inline the call.
- at link time, if LTO are enabled, the linker might decide to inline some calls.
- at load time, for the languages that support it.

All of them share a common point: they inline selectively, ie if it is worth at the point of call.

In C++, you can hint to the compiler that a function might be worth inlining using the `inline`, but it'll still perform a performance analysis with its own heuristics. The main use being that free functions declared inline do not lead to link failures because of duplicate symbols.

MSVC also supports `__forceinline` which forces inline... unless it's impossible (virtual call, function pointer, /O0, ...)

Therefore: it's not really possible to force / prevent inlining as far as I know. LTO even allows (in some circumstances) the inlining of virtual methods (which requires whole program analysis, thus is only suitable at the exec stage).

Comment: `__forceinline` is a lot more that just a hint, it overrides the compilers choice, unless the function cannot be inline'd, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx

Comment: @Necrolis: bad wording on my part, sorry, I consider it a hint because the compiler may not end-up inlining it. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 6):

please note that if you use the inline keyword, this is only a hint for the compiler. You cannot really control what the compiler inlines and what not.

If your compiler would follow your hints you could do:

```
inline void doItInline() {...}
void doItNonInline() {doItInline();}
```

Now you can call the method either inline'd or not.

Comment: Nothing prevents the compiler from inlining calls to `doItNonInline` anyway!

Comment: Perhaps the bigger question here is: are there good reasons for wanting to force a function not to be inlined by the compiler?

Comment: @Philipp_Now regarding this solution, what about doing it with class operators like equal operator cause they're some kinda function too?

Comment: Please note that I wrote "If your compiler would follow your hints", I didn't claim this was possible with a compiler I know. (@Konrad: For MS VC++ you can tell the compiler not to inline anything that is not marked inline, but that doesn't imply it would inline everything that is marked inline.)

Comment: The `inline` is *not* only a hint for the compiler. It introduces changes to the rules for the number and locations of allowed definitions for the function. The compiler is not allowed to ignore these rule changes even if it doesn't perform inline expansion of calls to an `inline` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to force it the other way around.

even though if you ask the compiler to inline, it can't do so if the definition is not available in the current compilation unit and has to create a call.

if you make sure the definition IS available, the compiler MIGHT inline it.

Comment: Oh, you're not using msvc, are you?

Comment: Even if the compiler can't inline a call, LTO might inline it anyway

Comment: mostly gcc :) the question does not mention which system :/

Comment: @Markus Winand, my point was that msvc can inline calls across translation unit boundaries. :) Also, there is an experimental branch of gcc that can do that (through link time code generation).

Comment: +1 for a raising a highly relevant and confusing point, even though I think in light of TokenMacGuy's insight you might change "can force" to "can try to force"...

Comment: @avakar - got that. Still that approach could possibly work in the environment where needed?

Comment: @Markus Winand, it could possibly work in the environment where needed *for now*. It certainly isn't a solid piece of engineering.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the in-line version with a non-inline defined version?

```
inline void f_inline () {}

void f_not_inline () {f_inline ();}
```

Comment: Nothing prevents the compiler from inlining calls to `f_not_inline` anyway!

Comment: Or not inlining calls to `f_inline` :)

Comment: @John_what about when dealing with user-defined operators since they're functions too?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use a macro :

```
#define myfunc_inlined(a,b) (a + b)

int myfunc(int a, int b)
{
    return myfunc_inlined(a,b);
}

int main()
{
    int i = myfunc_inlined(1, 3); #macro call
    int j = myfunc(1, 3);         #standard call
}
```

Comment: A macro is certainly not a function, too many issues to be worth mentioning for the job.